# NUNIT is ignoring my tests? Why?

Tags: nunit

I Have a really simple test class as below.

For some reason my test is being ignored by the GUI and coming up yellow.

I have updated the framework and runner to 2.4.8 as I thought it might have been differences between versions being the problem.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TestRunner
{
    [TestFixture]
    class TestMe
    {

        [Test]
        public void TestBob()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your TestMe class needs to be public.

Here is some [documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.4.8) on the requirements for classes marked with the TestFixture attribute that discusses the conditions under which a class may not be recognized as a test fixture.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify an access modifier for your class; therefore, your class is internal by default and NUnit does not see your class.

If you specify the **public access modifier** for your class that contains the Tests, then it should just work:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestMe
{
    [Test]
    public void TestBob()
    {
       Assert.AreEqual ("Bob", "Bob");
    }
}
```